# Do most conference papers get written last minute?

Tags: research-process, writing, early-career

When I began my PhD (in a STEM field; somewhat relevant), I had heard from a few people that most papers in my field get written at the last minute. I kind of took that as a personal quirk that those few people had.

I am now a little over half-way into the program, and have had the opportunity to work with many experienced researchers. Every paper I have been a part of did indeed end up being written at the last minute; sometimes just hours before the deadline. I like to start early and get a lot of the basic drafting done at least a few weeks in advance. This pattern that I have noticed in my colleagues causes me a lot of stress and anxiety, as a lot of things end up being changed close to the deadline, and a lot of my work -- that was initially acknowledged as correct -- ends up needing to be re-done in favor of last minute improvements. So essentially, I just end up doing the work twice.

I have always felt that making deliberate and steady progress was better than grinding. Perhaps academics are just very busy people (?) or perhaps I have only met people who prefer working this way. I would like to get a broad perspective on this from the Academia-SE community.

Is this how academic research is done in your respective fields? Is there a reasonable way to set expectations of myself and of others? I don't want to be pulling all-nighters for the rest of my career, so I look to those who feel the same way as myself for advice on how they make it work.

Comment: Are these conference papers? Journals don't usually have deadlines, except maybe for a special issue, and those have been so abused lately that I can't imagine ever publishing in one.

Comment: Yes, conference papers.

Comment: Well, for one, most fields don't rely on conference papers as a primary publishing venue. Let me guess - you're in CS (or AI/ML)?

Comment: Let's say, yes.

Comment: I get the sentiment behind this question, but the open-ended final paragraph pushes it into being structurally impossible to give one answer to the question as asked.

Comment: The point is to get a breadth of perspectives on how conference papers are written across areas. The last statement is secondary, and can be safely ignored if one wishes. Although you are correct in that there is no right answer, the guidelines do allow for some open-ended questions. Specifically this would be a question that "invite[s] sharing experiences over opinions" (direct quote).

Comment: *"I don't want to be pulling all-nighters for the rest of my career, so I look to those who feel the same way as myself for advice on how they make it work."* << This is called time management. If the deadline is at 7am on friday and you don't want to work all night, write the deadline as "7pm on thursday" on your personal calendar and you'll have finished writing your paper 12h in advance of the true deadline.

Comment: @Stef the problem is not OP's time management. The problem is that his colleagues expect him to work and make changes to the paper until the very minute of the deadline.

Comment: @wimi So replace "personal calendar" with "team calendar" in my previous comment, and turn your phone off at 7pm on thursday when you leave the lab. If you send the message "I will pick up the phone if you call me at 3am to make last-minute changes on a paper", then people ***will*** call you at 3am. But if you make it clear that you sleep at night, no one is going to punish you for not working during the night. Setting boundaries is actually not that hard if you do it clearly.

Comment: @Stef I completely agree, and that's how I always do it. Just wanted to clarify that in this case it is a problem of setting boundaries and not one of self discipline.

Comment: Once we have a result we are relatively happy with, we ask: when is the next conference for which this result is a relatively good fit? Oh, yikes, the deadline is this Friday. Well, perhaps we can make it.

Comment: @wimi Please don't assume that users are male.

Comment: In my experience, it depends on whether it's a paper for a top conference, or an average/good conference. Papers for a top conference take so much concentrated effort and polish that it's simply infeasible to write them last minute (but significant last-minute revisions surely exist).

Comment: Of course, most journal papers are finished 'at the last minute' in so far as when it is done you submit it. However, I certainly know some people who do a lot of the writing before even going into the lab to do the experiment. Sometimes they need to do extensive rewrites as the results are far from what was expected.

Answer (score 42):

Many academics wait until after the deadline to do things.  If you include those as "last minute" then it's surely more than half.

A funding agency told me an experimental test was done.  They got rid of the deadline for submitting applications.  Once it was no longer possible to wait until the last minute, the number of applications dropped very substantially.  This shows many applicants are unable to apply if they cannot wait until the deadline to do it.

> academics are just very busy people

Doing things at the last minute is not an efficient way to handle being very busy.

> Is there a reasonable way to set expectations of myself and of others?

"Lie" to them about the deadline.  If the deadline is January 1, tell them "Please help me submit this by December 1."  You do not need to actually lie; just present your preferred deadline without mentioning there is a separate, third party deadline.

> I don't want to be pulling all-nighters for the rest of my career

Say no.  Experiments might require working all night.  Paperwork deadlines never require it.

Comment: _This shows many applicants are unable to apply if they cannot wait until the deadline_ - or they assumed that their P(win) was much lower; no-deadline solicitations often don't have hard money behind them, at least at certain agencies.

Comment: @cag51 This agency alleged the quality standards were unchanged and the funding level was adjusted proportionately.  However, the details were unclear.

Comment: @cag51 A review of no-deadline approaches found here suggests that removing the deadline from a program is typically associated with lower submission rate in subsequent years, even in absence of other obvious changes to the program: https://nsf-gov-resources.nsf.gov/2022-05/NDL%20Literature%20Review%20Final%20508c_0.pdf

Comment: Doing things at the last minute is a very efficient way to handle being busy. In computing we have a name for it: the lazy algorithm is one that defers work to the last moment possible before doing it. This is useful because it avoid the situation where you proactively end up doing a bunch of work and then find out you didn't need to. By analogy, If I write up my paper abstract, intro, related work, methodology, and only then do I do the actual research work, I might find out that my paper goes in a completely different direction and I need to re-write all that stuff. Lazy is not derogatory.

Comment: @David That only applies if the different tasks have dependencies; most academics postpone unpleasant task A to do unrelated task B.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Not necessarily. If you write half a paper and your student gets hit by a bus, then you've just lost a bunch of work. No dependencies required. That obviously is not common, but sometimes things don't work out for non-dependency reasons. I am assuming that your average academic has enough stuff to do to productively fill up any free time they do have.

Comment: @David a simple algorithm for real-time scheduling is Earliest Deadline First, which does exactly what it says on the tin, and is the exact opposite of academics. By doing the work with the soonest deadline first, assuming there is enough time to do all the work, you minimize the chance of accidentally leaving some work too late and missing a deadline.

Comment: @David No, if I write half a paper and my student gets hit by a bus, I write the other half of the paper and publish it.  If your students do not keep good records you might have trouble with that, but I do not.

Comment: @user253751 And EDF Is notorious for being difficult to implement!

Comment: @David as I understand it, the hard part is proving there is always enough time to do all the work. The actual EDF algorithm is very simple! In case there is not enough time - the system is overloaded - EDF can cause cascading deadline misses, while a smarter algorithm could cancel some work with earlier impossible deadlines in order to ensure that other deadlines are still met.

Comment: Depending on who you work with, lying about the deadline won't be possible. As a PhD student, I published mostly together with my advisor and/or other research assistants from the same institute. Interesting Calls for Papers were usually shared within the group, so everyone knew all the deadlines.

Comment: "Doing things at the last minute is not an efficient way to handle being very busy." This ignores the psychological fact that some people work more efficiently last-minute.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper That would assume people cannot change, which they can.

Answer (score 18):

I can’t speak for the field (computer science), but I find that to be either an exaggerated claim or evidence of something that really broke in the specific lab.

The written manuscript is an evolving document that changes with the research. It is not (ideally) the result of the research but rather a means of building and formalizing it. In a sense, it *is* the research.

Thus, it feels unlikely that someone came up with an idea, a model, ran experiments and wrote them up, all within a week of a deadline. At least not while maintaining some research standards.

What’s more likely is that some final results/issues are still worked through, which creates last-minute scrambles. This is not the same as “the paper got written last minute “.

Comment: Okay, I can agree with that. It is a valid perspective.

Comment: This isn't true for everyone.  Some people do experiments and data analysis for a year, then spend one day writing the paper.

Comment: To clarify -- I didn't say my field was computer science. I only said it was okay to assume that it was.

Comment: @bbq Publishing practices vary *a lot* by field so if you want specific answer, you'll have to mention a specific field.

Comment: I do _not_ want a specific answer. The point is to get a breadth of perspectives on how conference papers are written across areas.

Comment: @bbq: This isn't the platform for that: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @BenVoigt: As I said in another comment, I believe this is a constructive question as it "invite[s] sharing experiences over opinions." Still, if you do not find it appropriate, it is fine if you vote to close it.

Comment: @bbq: Bullets 2 and 3 of the *avoid* list apply, and only because you're looking for "breadth of perspectives"

Comment: @bbq But the meaning what a conference paper is is very different in different disciplines. In Physics and Mechanical Engineering I went to several conferences where many authors presented work that they already published in journals before and invited the audience to read those papers.

Comment: In the non-academic side (open-source related conferences), "conference-driven development" is a well-known phenomenon, and if you see someone in the hotel lobby with a laptop the night before the conference (or on one of the early days of the conference) and ask them what they're doing, "working on my slides" is a very common response, as is "just cutting a release so I can tell people that the thing my talk is about is actually *available*".

Answer (score 8):

### Some research is never 'finished'

One issue of artificial deadlines is with respect to the (many!) kinds of research reports where the boundaries are fuzzy enough that deciding when to publish is effectively an arbitrary choice - in such papers you're reporting your findings and progress on a topic where one can always do more.

For papers like that, you're effectively reporting the "best known result as of this deadline" and it doesn't make sense to prepare the data and analysis in advance if you're not going to publish it right now, since a month later you'll have better data from newer experiments. This leads to intentionally planning the project explicitly working backwards from the deadline, expecting to finish at it, but not leaving much extra time.

The other reasonably frequent situation is to plan based on the end of some funding grant, where you'd want to wrap up all the work (including the publication) by a specific deadline after which you stop paying the involved people to work on that project - and again, you want to report on *all* the experiments you manage to complete within that project, so the paper can only be finalized close to the last minute.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to conference papers it really depends on your field. In chemistry true conference papers are almost non-existent, and conference abstracts are really almost always written shortly before the deadline and also without much care (they are usually not even considered a decent publication, but merely an intention about which topic one wants to speak about), while in computer science conference papers are usually fully worked out research reports. For full papers I know the need to write them for a deadline only in regard with intermediate/final grant reports or sometimes themed issues of a journal, especially if meant to honor someone's birthday. One cannot always prevent this madness, unless one is the leader of one's own group (but then there are still the grant reports). So, from my experience, it is not the standard in my field, and many colleagues of me, and myself too, prefer to write their papers without any deadlines, since, in my opinion, this kind of slower writing can help to improve the paper in many regards. Sometimes one just needs time to think, and scientist should claim this time irrespective of any deadlines.